# convert with group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table :

```
 pedido data
 314    2013-04-05 00:00:00.000
 318    2013-04-05 00:00:00.000
 319    2013-04-05 00:00:00.000          
 26025  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
 26026  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 
 26026  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
 26026  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
 26026  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
 26027  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
 26029  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
 26029  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want this result :

```
 314        2013-04-05
 318        2013-04-05
 319        2013-04-05
26025       2013-07-01
26026       2013-07-01
26027       2013-07-01
26029       2013-07-01
```

I have try with this but is not working :

```
   select pedido,data from alteraca  group by data,pedido order by pedido
```

and this :

```
  select pedido, (CONVERT varchar(10),data,101)  as fecha1  from alteraca
```

This code have worked for me :

```
      select pedido, MIN (data) as data from alteraca 
      group by pedido order by pedido
```

one little detail how i can show only the date part

```
  14        2013-04-05
  318       2013-04-05
```

not

```
  14        2013-04-05 00:00:00.000 
  318       2013-04-05 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found `group by`. Please check the documentation for the exact syntax. Assuming you want the lowest date, you can do this:

```
select 
  pedido,
  min(data) as data 
from alteraca  
group by pedido 
order by pedido
```

If you just want to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct
  pedido,
  data
from alteraca  
order by pedido
```

In either case you can exchange `date` with `(CONVERT varchar(10), data) as data` if you want to do a conversion to char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select Distinct pedido, CONVERT(varchar(10),data)  as fecha1  from alteraca
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is already right!

```
select pedido,data from alteraca  group by data,pedido order by pedido
```

Check out this [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/697a3/1).

**Output (From Fiddle):**

```
PEDIDO  DATA
314         April, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000
318         April, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000
319         April, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000
26025   July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
26026   July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
26027   July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
26029   July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Comment: It is correct, but it is a complex way to write `select distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using mssql 2008, you can use cast(data as date):

```
SELECT pedido, cast(min(data) as date) as data
FROM table
GROUP BY pedido
ORDER BY pedido
```

If you want to convert to a char(10) or use an earlier version of sqlserver, you can use this syntax, the advanage here is that you will always get the same format on the output - exactly like described in your question:

```
SELECT pedido, convert(char(10), min(data), 120) as data
FROM table
GROUP BY pedido
ORDER BY pedido
```